# Azure North Europe or West Europe for an Irish Website

Tags: azure

We are deploying an Azure Application for use by an Irish userbase. There are two datacentres we could use: North Europe (Dublin) or West Europe (Amsterdam).

Should we deploy to North Europe (after all, the datacantre is in Dublin)
or
Should we deploy to West Eurpore (Ireland is in West Europe, more than it is in North Europe)

Comment: North Europe! http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/ ;)

Answer (score 4):

In general a datacenter in your same country will be fastest so North Europe for your users, but it ultimately depends on the network peering and route between your users and the datacenter so there is no one-size-fits-all answer.

The best answer is to test.  Deploy something to both datacenters and see which is fastest for your particular users.  An easy way to do this is to utilize http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/.  Just have your users browse that site and tell you which datacenter is fastest.  This may not model your service exactly, but should be a close approximation.